# How to access data returned via method per item in v-for

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js, vuejs2

I am calling a method from each item in a `v-for`. The method returns the proper object but I want to access that information in other pieces of my `.card`. Such as having the `{{name}}` reflect the sponsor's name returned from that method. Normally I would have the method push the data to Vue data and then access via item. But that would be strange to do for 200+ items. (Perhaps I'm missing something in that logic)

I have the following VueJS setup:

HTML:

```
<div v-for="deal in deals">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>{{deal.name}}</h3>
    <p>{{ getSponsor(key) }}</p>
    <p>{{sponsor.name}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
firebase () {
  return {
    deals: db.ref('deals'),
    businesses: db.ref('businesses')
  }
},
methods: {
  getDealSponsor (key) {
    db.ref('businesses').child(key).on('value', snap => {
      return snap.val()
    })
  }
}
```

JSON:

```
deals
  -SomeDeal(Firebase Key)
    name: "Some Deal"
    provider: -SomeBusiness (Firebase KEy)
businesses
  -SomeBusiness (Firebase KEy)
    name: "Some Business Name"
```

Comment: Why not load all of your data into an array first and then loop over the data?

Comment: @thanksd I have to loop through all of my deals array first but each deal has a sponsor in a businesses array which is very large. Essentially I'm doing a weird query/join trick to find the business sponsoring a deal looped via `v-for`. I edited my question to make this more obvious.

Comment: yeah but still, you could loop over the deals array in your script to load all of the sponsors into an array and then reference that in the template

Comment: I added my JSON, not sure I'm following. Does what you're saying still work with that JSON format? The businesses array has hundreds of objects. And deal/businesses data does not line up 1 for 1. Some have 10 some have none, hence the `provider` key which I use to look up the provider and get their information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no real way to make a "temporary variable" inside a loop, but you can use the fact that `v-for` makes an alias for what it's looping over:

```
<div v-for="deal in deals">
  <div class="card">
    <h3>{{deal.name}}</h3>
    <template v-for="sponsor in [getSponsor(key)]">
      <p>{{ sponsor }}</p>
      <p>{{sponsor.name}}</p>
    </template>
  </div>
</div>
```

If `key` is just a prop to component, then you can make a computed based on it:

```
sponsor() {
  return getSponsor(key);
}
```

and use it as I used the alias above.

Comment: `key` gets passed as a prop to the component but is essentially just the `-SomeDeal(Firebase Key)` part in my JSON. But this looks great, I'll give it a try!

Comment: So can you just make a simple computed, as in my (edited) answer?

Comment: It seems to work, I'm having trouble as the `method` returns the correct `object` but the `method` called from the `computed` results in `undefined`. Looking into this now.

Comment: This did end up working and was an answer to my question. I also had a teammate point out that you can (if the card is its own component) set the `sponsor` in Vue `data` and then set it equal to the `snap.val` in the method then call the `method` via `mounted`. Just thought I'd offer that up in case it helps anyone.